# Regex to include and exclude certain IPs

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

I have a functional python 2.7 code that extracts IPs from the routing table.  It only extracts ip in x.x.x.x/xx format.  I do however has a issue excluding some lines in the route table.

For example, this line:

```
D       10.50.80.0/24 [90/3072] via 10.10.10.1, 3w6d, Vlan10
```

In this line all I care about is 10.50.80.0/24. Since this is the only ip with /24 notation, I can only grab that and have regex ignore onces without / (e.g, 10.10.10.1). But in the table, we have below 2 anomalies:

```
     10.10.60.0/16 is variably subnetted, 58 subnets, 4 masks
C       10.10.140.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan240
```

I would like to capture the IP on second line (10.10.140.0/24) but not first line (10.10.60.0/16).  The program is extracting IPs and checking if any subnet is available in table or not.  10.10.60.0/16 is issue as it is not saying that 10.10.60.0/16 is in table but only saying that this subnet has variable subnetting.

Currently my tool is capturing this IP and marking whole 10.10.60.0/16 range as in table which is not true.  I tried some regex edit but was not really happy with it.  I do not accidentally want to skip any subnet accidentally especially the second line that is similar to first. It is very important to capture all correct subnets.

Can someone suggest a best regex edit to accomplish this.  Only skip lines that has **x.x.x.x/xx is variably subnetted, x subnets, x masks**

Here is my current code:

```
match = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
```

Thanks
Damon

Comment: This looks like output from `show ip route` on a Cisco device - the actual routes in the table (i.e. not summaries) will always have a letter as the first character to indicate the origin of the route (static, connected, OSPF, EIGRP, etc). You can just discard lines that start with a space, or only look at lines that start with the few possible letters (`show ip route` tells you what is possible).

Comment: That is a good solution but there is a chance it might miss an actual IP due to unexpected space or something.  I believe the bottom solution is more safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly you want your existing regex to skip any IP/subnet that is followed by **'is variably subnetted'**. Do that that you can use this regex:

```
(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})\b(?! is variably)
```

- I've added `\b(?! is variably)` at the end of your regex
- `\b` at the end indicates a word boundary
- `(?! is variably)` has a negative lookahead `(?!` which makes sure that the text ' is variably' isn't present after the IP/subnet.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jTu8cj/1

Matches:

```
D       10.50.80.0/24 [90/3072] via 10.10.10.1, 3w6d, Vlan10
C       10.10.140.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan240
```

Doesn't match:

```
10.10.60.0/16 is variably subnetted, 58 subnets, 4 masks
255.255.255.1
```

Comment: Worked fine.  I had something similar but without \b.