# Exclude an IP from a regex that extract IPs from text file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I posted a question regarding this before but forgot about an additional case.  Here is my first question:

[Regex to include and exclude certain IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788990/regex-to-include-and-exclude-certain-ips)

The additional case is this line in routing table:

```
D*EX 0.0.0.0/0 [170/19664] via 10.10.10.1, 5d22h, Vlan10
           [170/19664] via 10.10.10.1, 5d22h, Vlan20
```

How to I edit my regex to exclude 0.0.0.0/0 IP from my below regex:

```
(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})\b(?! is variably)
```

I tried these but it did not work:

```
(?! 0.0.0.0/0)(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})\b(?! is variably)
                                 AND
(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})\b(?! is variably)(?! 0.0.0.0/0)
```

Thanks

Damon

Comment: You don't need to do this in a regex. You're just making it harder for yourself. Keep your regex the same, then in your program logic (this is Python, after all), disregard the `0.0.0.0` address. Your program will be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Greg Hewgill commented, I think you can use `if` statement.

```
if ('0.0.0.0/0' not in text) and ('is variably' not in text):
    match = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})\b', text)
```

If you really want to use regex to solve it, this is it. https://regex101.com/r/jTu8cj/2

`(?!0\.0\.0\.0/0)(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})\b(?! is variably)`

```
# Positive
D       10.50.80.0/24 [90/3072] via 10.10.10.1, 3w6d, Vlan10
C       10.10.140.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan240
10.10.140.0/2
10.10.140.0/16
2.2.2.2/24
5.5.5.5.5/24

# Negative
10.0.0.0
     10.10.60.0/16 is variably subnetted, 58 subnets, 4 masks
0.0.0.0/0 [170/19664] via 10.10.10.1, 5d22h, Vlan10
```

Comment: Good idea  :)  I went with if statements for both cases and regex for rest (your first suggestion) and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad I helped :)